# German internship visa to job visa conversion

Tags: germany, german-citizens

I applied for a German internship visa recently and the process is in its final stages. My employer told me today that he would like to hire me full-time after the internship. So is it possible to get a new employment visa in Germany itself without coming back? What is the procedure to obtain it?